# Unknown formatter "sentence" error in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Factory definition:

```
public function definition()
{
    return [
        'user_id' => function() {
            return User::factory()->create()->id;
        },
        'category_id' => function() {
            return Category::factory()->create()->id;
        },
        'title' => $this->faker->sentence,
        'body' => $this->faker->paragraph,
    ];
}
```

The test that throws an error

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit;

use App\Models\Question;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class QuestionTest extends TestCase
{
    protected $question;

    public function setUp() : void
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->question = Question::factory()->create();
    }


    public function test_it_has_an_owner()
    {
        $this->assertInstanceOf('App\User', $this->question->creator);
    }
}
```

that is the error:

There was 1 error:

```
1) Tests\Unit\QuestionTest::test_it_has_an_owner
InvalidArgumentException: Unknown formatter "sentence"

/var/www/html/QA_CRUD/vendor/fzaninotto/faker/src/Faker/Generator.php:248
/var/www/html/QA_CRUD/vendor/fzaninotto/faker/src/Faker/Generator.php:228
/var/www/html/QA_CRUD/vendor/fzaninotto/faker/src/Faker/Generator.php:285
/var/www/html/QA_CRUD/database/factories/QuestionFactory.php:34
/var/www/html/QA_CRUD/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Factories/Factory.php:366
/var/www/html/QA_CRUD/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Factories/Factory.php:345
/var/www/html/QA_CRUD/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Factories/Factory.php:329
/var/www/html/QA_CRUD/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/GuardsAttributes.php:157
/var/www/html/QA_CRUD/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Factories/Factory.php:334
/var/www/html/QA_CRUD/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Factories/Factory.php:302
/var/www/html/QA_CRUD/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Factories/Factory.php:228
/var/www/html/QA_CRUD/tests/Unit/QuestionTest.php:16
```

What is the problem i know that sentence key is indeed exists in the faker

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if those should be `$this->faker->sentence()` and `$this->faker->paragraph()` ie with `()` as function calls

Comment: I've tried that at first :). It seems to me that the problem is only in this test. When i use factory via laravel tinker everything works fine

Comment: When you use `()` do you get the exact same error? If not can you add that error?

Comment: Yep as i said tried that at first, got exactly the same error

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You are not extending the correct `TestCase`.

Simply replace the following:

```php
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
```

By:

```
use Tests\TestCase;
```

You can overwrite the default stub by running `php artisan stub:publish` and update `stubs/test.unit.stub` to extend the correct TestCase.

For more information about customizing stubs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/artisan#stub-customization

Comment: True, I think this should be the problem here. Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase is extended in Tests/Testcase.

Comment: Yes you right. How can i make laravel automatically create correct unit tests with php artisan make:test command?

Comment: I've added it to my answer.

Comment: Yes, Just change in "test.unit.stub" file after publishing stubs.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this in your factory class (e.g. UserFactory), simply change any Faker values to, for example, for Person:

```
    $factory = \Faker\Factory::create('en');
    $faker = new \Faker\Provider\Person($factory);
```

Then use it like:

```
$faker->title()
```